# How to create a dynamic path inside a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

I created a command line program in java that will be deployed. Since it has no windows it can't be run by double clicking. I then created a batch file that will run the jar but since the program will be deployed they will have a different path than me.

How do I go from:

```
java -jar E:\Projects\Java\SystemFileQuery\SFSQ.jar
```

to:

```
java -jar ...\SFSQ.jar
```

Comment: please reedit your question and make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deploy the `SFSQ.jar` file to the same directory as your batch file and then you can use

```
   java -jar SFSQ.jar
```